# Servlets - handling login and session

Tags: java, session, servlets, amazon-web-services

I am working on a service that provides some data and supports basic CRUD operations over them. There are multiple users in my system and they have access to different data and have different permissions. That means that I have to implement a login and session management which is easy and scalable (it does not have to be bullet-proof in terms of security, it is just a project). The session has to be kept over many requests - not just accessing one page after login.

The whole project is based on servlets and JSP and I am not sure which way to handle this. By looking at some examples and articles, I am choosing between these approaches (I am new to this problematic and would love to hear your opinions on correct implementation decission):

1) Create session beans and keep the session active the whole time. -> I don't like this solution very much since it creates a lot of computational overhead and it does not seem to be very efficient in case of many simultaneous connections.

2) Basic servlets with cookies. Client will keep a cookie and use it when performing requests.

3) Sending authorization information in each request. -> Does not seem very user friendly for the client.

4) Using session ID and sending this ID with each request (the ID has to be remembered on client side).

Which approach is the correct one for such system (assuming that it should be scalable).

Comment: What do you mean by "create session beans and keep the session active"? What's the difference between 2 and 3? What's wrong with HttpSession?

Comment: I am looking for a solution which creates minimal overhead (and using sessionBeans is discouraged unless necessary, or so I have heard). By 2) I meant using cookie and by 3) sending username and password in each request.. which now does sound stupid.

Comment: You're still not saying what you mean by "session bean". Are you using EJBs? Because session beans are part of the EJB specification, and don't have anything to do with maintaining a session with a specific client. What's wrong with HttpSession?

Comment: Yes, I meant EJB beans. I forgot to check httpSession, will have to look at it closer. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

The cookie approach sounds good to me. It's easy to implement and you'll only need a Filter to check on the Cookie for each request.

Anyway, you should try something more standard provided by your app server out of the box: Java EE declarative security. Have a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/820-4803/gatai/index.html and this https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#UserDatabaseRealm

Answer (score 0):

I assume by now you have found `HttpServletRequest.login()`? If not, that is probably what you are looking for.